# Multile pthread_cond_wait waken up and hold the mutex lock

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

According to the man page, **pthread_cond_broadcast** wakes up all the threads that are waiting on condition variable (condvar). And those waken threads will hold back the mutex lock and return from **pthread_cond_wait**.

But what I am confusing is: Isn't it the mutex lock should held by only one thread in the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition variables work like this:

```
/* Lock a mutex. */
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

/* Wait on condition variable. */
while (/* condition *.)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);

/* When pthread_cond_wait returns mtx is atomically locked. */

/* ... */

/* Unlock the mutex. */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
```

So the main point to understand is that many threads can wake up when a broadcast is sent, but **only one will "win" the race** and actually lock `mtx` and get out of the loop.

Comment: cnicutar: That means only **one** thread will return from pthread_cond_wait(),others will remain blocked. am I right?

Comment: @Martin: To be clear- only one thread *at a time* will return from the `pthread_cond_wait()` call (the one that holds the mutex).  The others will return (one by one) when the mutex is released.  Whether or not they get out of the `while` loop depends on whether or not the condition remains true or gets rest to false by the first (or subsequent) thread.